# how to use jquery aci tree plugin in angular js directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, acitree

I have to use acitree jquery plugin (Source: http://acoderinsights.ro/source/aciTree/aciTree-radio.html) in angular js, in-order to list all my trees.

Help me how to use jquery aci-tree plugin in angularjs directive... Thanks in advance!!

Comment: let me know if my guess is correct, you want to build a custom angularjs directive which will work as a wrapper of http://acoderinsights.ro/source/aciTree/aciTree-radio.html?

Comment: You can search SO for many questions like this.  Blending jQuery components into your angular app is a pain in the neck.  Avoid it if you can.  Usually  you can find a similar component that is native angular.  If you can't  you can probably piece together an answer by searching SO.

Comment: @jbrown is right. however if you really need a wrapper directive for a plugin there is lots of resource in internet. may be you will find something useful into https://bencentra.com/code/2015/09/29/jquery-plugins-angular-directives.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Still i need to go ahead with this jquery injection as it has better UI than angular js tree component. Trying as my best. Hope will soon meet with answer. @jbrown what is meant by SO?

Comment: Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long try, i obtain a solution and seems it working fine.After including neccessary acitree include file, here i had written directive to include acitree in angular js.

```
.directive('aciTree', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      content: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element) {
      scope.$watch('content', function () {
        scope.checkTreeEvent = function(event, api, item, eventName, options) { 
            var id = api.getId(item);
            switch (eventName) {                
                case 'checked':
                    break;
                case 'unchecked':
                    break;
            }    
        }
        if (scope.content) {
          element.aciTree(scope.content).bind('acitree', scope.checkTreeEvent);
        }
      });
    }
  };
})
```

Included the following code in html page:

```
<div id="tree" ng-show="!errorMsg" aci-tree content="options" class="aciTree" style="height:265px;overflow:auto;"></div>
```

JSON for the tree can be included in the controller as follows:

```
var data = [{
        "id":101,
        "label":"Total Vehicle Range",
        "inode":true,
        "checkbox":false,
        "radio":false,
        "branch":[{
            "id":102,
            "label":"75 miles",
            "inode":false,
            "checkbox":false,
            "radio":true
        },
        {
            "id":103,
            "label":"300 miles",
            "inode":false,
            "checkbox":false,
            "radio":true
        },
        {
            "id":104,
            "label":"500 miles",
            "inode":false,
            "checkbox":false,
            "radio":true
        },
        {
            "id":105,
            "label":"700 miles",
            "inode":false,
            "checkbox":false,
            "radio":true
        }]
    }];
scope.options = {
              rootData: data,
              checkbox: true
            };
```

Hope this help someone!!!!